# T4MVC controller generated files not updating for newly added controller

Tags: t4mvc

I added T4MVC into my application and it generated all necessary files for the controllers.
However when i try to add a new controller into my application, but I dont see the controller.generated file for this newly added controller into the application.

Am I missing something or is it a limitation of T4MVC?
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

There are several options to cause the generation to happen:

- it happens whenever you save the t4mvc.tt file
- you can right click t4mvc.tt and choose Run Custom Tool
- You can use Chirpy (http://chirpy.codeplex.com/), which can make T4MVC generation automatic.

Comment: should also be added that as an alternative to chirpy you can also set the settings option AlwaysKeepTemplateDirty to true so it keeps its state to unsaved and regenerates itself on each build which is what i do as chirpy seems to have issues with our windows xp install at work

Comment: Yep, that was the 'original' solution. It's a bit quirky, but it does work :)